# Why does the STL reserve an interface for Allocator?

Tags: c++

Why does the STL reserve an interface for Allocator?
Taking `vector` as example:

```
template<class T,class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> 
class vector;
```

Since there are many options for us to allocate memory and construct objects like
`operator new,delete,new[],delete[]`,which could do almost anything we need when we create an object.
So why does the STL containers like `vector` need an Allocator interface,which at most time is the default `std::allocator` if we don't assgin one? **Why not just use the `new` expressions?**
If the purpose is to make user-defined allocating behaviors possible,why not just let the users provide their self-defined `operator new,new[]`,etc?

Comment: If you wanted to change how the vector allocated it's memory how would you do it if there was no allocator?

Comment: @NathanOliver If the purpose is to make user-defined allocating behaviors possible,why not just let the users provide their self-defined `operator new,new[]`,etc?

Comment: You can't overload `new` for an `int` unless you overload the global one which you might not want to do.

Comment: Because its much easier to write a custom `Allocator` than it is to write a custom `std::vector`.

Comment: @bigxiao how would `std::vector` know whether you intend to use the standard new versus your custom new?

Comment: If you wanted to change how *exactly one* vector, *of many* that hold a particular type, allocated it's memory how would you do it if there was no allocator?

Comment: @NathanOliver You're right for the bult-in types.But at most time the objects we insert into the containers are self-defined classes.What's more,i do not think it is necessary and useful for us to define a self-defined allocating behavior for the  bult-in types.If you do not think so,could you provide an example?

Comment: @bigxiao C++ is designed to be as general as possible (everything from micro-controllers with no heap to supercomputers with distributed memory).  Providing an allocator accomplishes that.  It's really not that big of a deal considering it is defaulted so if you don't want to use a custom allocator you don't need to do anything.  The allocator though is more flexible than what you could do with overloading the `new` operators.

Comment: @Caleth What about providing self-defined `operator new`,although it does not  change the bult-in types

Comment: How does that distinguish between `vector<Foo> first` and `vector<Foo> second`, when you want `first` to allocate with one rule and `second` with a different rule? (Hint: it can't)

Comment: @bigxiao you can check chapter 4 of Modern C++ Design by Andrei Alexandrescu for example

Comment: @AndrewKashpur Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Caleth You're right.I have to say the guys who design the STL are so cool.

Comment: I don't follow this question at all. You ask why the standard library "reserves an interface" (don't know what this means) then give all the reasons why the current design is good.

Comment: _"why not just let the users provide their self-defined operator new,new[],etc?"_ Well, that's exactly what allowing you to provide an allocator does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So specific vector and change how it allocates without changing how all vectors allocate.

`new` must be overridden on a per-type basis of what you are allocating, or replaced globally.  `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<int, some_other_allocator>` can use a different allocation strategy; in fact, the allocator can be *stateful* and have *shared state*.

A classic one is a fast stack allocator that doesn't deallocate until it goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.By the way i think the term " **overriden** " may not be suitble here,maybe " **replaced** " is better.See [document of "replacement"](http://eel.is/c++draft/replacement.functions)

Comment: @bigxiao Overriding and replacing new are different things with different purposes.  Both apply here.

Answer (score 1):

For example `std::list<T, Allocator>` also provides this interface. Usually you are told not to use linked lists because of bad cache-locality.

If you still need to use a linked list since for example it never invalidates iterators you can optimize `std::list` by using a [pool allocator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/pool/doc/html/header/boost/pool/pool_alloc_hpp.html)

```
#include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>

template <typename T>
using pooled_list = std::list<T, boost::pool_allocator<T>>
```

This way you can optimize your code without re-implementing `std::list`. This is an example of [policy based design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design). Another example would be [`std::char_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) for [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).